# Debian 12: pam_tally2 gone?

Tags: debian, pam

I am using pam_tally2 on an old Debian 10 to cound failed logins.

Now I was trying to do the same on Debian 12. But it seems there is not pam_tally2 anymore.

Whats the idea to count (only count, not lockout) failed authentication attempts now?

Answer (score 3):

`pam_lastlog.so` will count and show the number of failed logins if you give it the `showfailed` option.

If that won't suit your needs, `pam_faillock.so` is part of the standard `libpam-modules` package now. If you set the "number of consecutive authentication failures allowed before locking" (the `deny` parameter) very high, or the `unlock_time` parameter to the lowest possible value of 1 second, might it also be applicable?

Comment: I have libpam-modules and libpam-modules-bin installed but cant find a binary pam_lastlog or pam_faillock...?

Comment: The libraries should be in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_lastlog.so` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_faillock.so` in x86_64 architecture on Debian 12. There is no `pam_lastlog` binary, did you mean `lastlog` or `lastb` (both in `/usr/bin`)? `/usr/sbin/faillock` does exist.

Comment: `pam_faillock` is the documented replacement for `pam_tally` (more precisely, `pam_tally` and `pam_tally2` were deprecated in favour of `pam_faillock`).